# Use std::result_of_t correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm having this strange problem that I can't wrap my head around. For this code:

```
struct Foo {
    int operator()() const & { return 0; }
    double operator()() const && { return 0; }
};

template<typename F>
void test(F&& f)
{
    static_assert<is_same<F&&, decltype(f)>::value, "!");  // (1)

    // intentionally not forwarding f
    using T1 = decltype(f());
    using T2 = result_of_t<decltype(f)()>;
    using T3 = result_of_t<F&&()>;
    using T4 = result_of_t<F&()>;

    static_assert(is_same<T1, T2>::value, "!");  // (2)
    static_assert(is_same<T1, T3>::value, "!");  // (3)
    static_assert(is_same<T1, T4>::value, "!");  // (4)
}

Foo f;
test(f);  // all static_asserts passed
test(Foo{});  // (1) and (4) passed, (2) and (3) failed
```

Since (1) seems to say `decltype(f)` is `F&&`, I guess (2) and (3) are actually the same. So, how could `decltype(f())` and `result_of_t<decltype(f)()>` disagree? And why are `decltype(f())` and `result_of_t<F&()>` the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the `test(Foo{})` call `decltype(f)` tells you that `f` was declared as an rvalue reference type, `Foo&&`, but that's the type it was declared with, it doesn't tell you what its value category is (i.e. rvalue or lvalue).

Within the body of the function `f` is an lvalue (because it has a name), so `decltype(f())` is not the same as `result_of_t<F&&()>`

Consider:

```
Foo&& f = Foo{};
f();
```

Here too, `f` is declared as an rvalue reference type, `Foo&&`, but that doesn't mean that `f()` invokes the `&&`-qualified member function. `f` is an lvalue, so it invokes the `&`-qualified overload. To invoke the `&&`-qualified overload you need to use `std::move(f)()` to make it an rvalue.

In your `test(F&&)` function where you have a universal reference you need to use `std::forward` to restore the value category of the incoming argument. To get the same type as `result_of_t<decltype(f)()>` you need to forward `f` to restore its original value category, e.g.

```
using T1 = decltype(std::forward<F>(f)());
```

Now that will have the same type as `result_of_t<decltype(f)()>`

Comment: Ah, now I begin to understand! So if I'm not forwarding a named functor when I call it, I should always be using `result_of_t<F&(...)>`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't say it like that. I would say that you should ensure the type you use with `result_of` matches the value category of the functor when you are invoking it. If you plan to invoke the call operator of an lvalue, use `result_of` with an lvalue type. If you plan to invoke the call operator of an rvalue, use `result_of` with an rvalue type. If you plan to invoke the call operator on a perfectly forwarding object then use `result_of` with the deduced type.

Comment: @jona except if you deduced `T` in `T&&`, following your advice requires unpacking what forwarding references do and how something can be declared as an rvalue reference but be an lvalue.  Following Ziz's advice does not.  Now, in practice, fulky groking forwarding references may be useful, but saying "do not use rules of thumb" has a steep learning curve.

Comment: Yes, but i don't think "to get the result of invoking an lvalue use `result_of` with an lvalue, and to get the result of invoking an rvalue, use `result_of` with an rvalue" really involves grokking much. Knowing that a named variable declared as an rvalue reference is not an rvalue is important, not just in this case, but whenever you write functions with rvalue reference or forwarding reference parameters. Beginners should not be writing functions with rvalue ref or forwarding ref params, but if you're writing them you should understand them.

Comment: Jonathan mentioned it, but i want to repeat, because i think this is the cause of misunderstanding here. Things that are declared as rvalue reference can be lvalues or rvalues. The distinguishing criterion is: if it has a name, then it is an lvalue. Otherwise, it is an rvalue. The rationale behind this is that allowing move sematics to be applied tacitly to something that has a name would be dangerously confusing and error-prone. More info [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html)